# How can I do something after Elapsed Time in Android?

Tags: android, sdk, elapsedtime

I am new in programming.

I want to turn off wifi after 2h (I know how to turn it off) in the background

I googled and found out, that the Elapsed Real Timer is needed for that. I have also find this code and implemented it (this is the only code I have in my class) This class is called when the user selects something from a spinner dropdown:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Wird aufgerufen, wenn eine Zeit von der dropdown liste gewählt wurde
 */
public class ElapsedRealtimeAlarm extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        PendingIntent mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getService(ElapsedRealtimeAlarm.this,
                0, new Intent(ElapsedRealtimeAlarm.this, ElapsedRealtimeAlarm.class), 0);
        long  firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(); // elapsedRealTime --> Zeit seitdem booten.
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,      // die 2h (1*1000*3600*2) werden von der Bootzeit(firstTime) dazugerechnet
                firstTime, 1*1000*3600*2, mAlarmSender);                     //  1*1000 --> 1s * 3600 --> 1h * 2 --> 2h
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Das ist ein Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Is the code until yet fine? And how can I turn wifi off after the elapsed timer?
And does this the elapsed timer only one time or is this like an interval?

Sorry for my english

Thanks

**EDIT**:

I did the steps, mentioned in the answer of "Deb" and it is still nothing happening
Here the code
Step 1: "Make a `BroadcatReceiver` extending `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`"

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class BroadCastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new BackgroundService(); // Step 4
    }
}
```

Step 2: Make a service extending `IntentService` Class
Step 3: In your service inside `onHandleIntent()` write your code for switching the wifi off or on.

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BackgroundService extends IntentService {

    public BackgroundService() {
        super("BackgroundService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
        } else {
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }
    }
```

Step 4: Now go back to your `BroadcastReceiver` class and there inside `onReceive()` call your service that you made in step 2 (the code is already in step 1)

Manifest file (receiver, service and permissions for wifi)

```
<manifest ..... ..... ....>
<application>
.....
<receiver android:name=".BroadCastReceiver" ></receiver>
        <service android:name=".BackgroundService" android:exported="false"></service>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

**EDIT 2**

The class where I am executing `startActivity(new Intent(SpinnerTimeOnItemSelectedListener.this, ElapsedRealtimeAlarm.class));`

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SpinnerTimeOnItemSelectedListener extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equals("Zeit auswählen") || parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equals("Select Time")){
            //onNothingSelected(parent);
            ;
        } else if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equals("30min")){
            startActivity(new Intent(SpinnerTimeOnItemSelectedListener.this, ElapsedRealtimeAlarm.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Wenn es einen ElapsedRealTimeAlarm gibt, soll er gecancelt werden
        // Ansonsten nichts
        ;
    }
}
```

`ElapsedRealtimeAlarm's onCreate()`

```
   public class ElapsedRealtimeAlarm extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ElapsedRealTimeAlarm wurde aufgerufen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // just to check, that he called this class
        PendingIntent mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getService(ElapsedRealtimeAlarm.this,
                0, new Intent(ElapsedRealtimeAlarm.this, BroadCastReceiver.class), 0);
        long  firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(); // elapsedRealTime --> Zeit seitdem booten.
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,      // die 2h (1*1000*3600*2) werden von der Bootzeit(firstTime) dazugerechnet
                firstTime+2000, 10, mAlarmSender);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make a `BroadcatReceiver` extending `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` .
2. Make a service extending `IntentService` Class.
3. In your service inside `onHandleIntent()` write your code for switching the wifi off or on.
4. Now go back to your BroadcastReceiver class and there inside onReceive() call your service that you made in step 2.

Your line of code

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,      // die 2h (1*1000*3600*2) werden von der Bootzeit(firstTime) dazugerechnet
            firstTime, 1*1000*3600*2, mAlarmSender);
```

This is responsible for running an alarmmanager repeatedly after every 2hrs.But if u want the alarm manager to run only once replace `am.setRepeating()` with `am.set()`.

Your Code

```
PendingIntent mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getService(ElapsedRealtimeAlarm.this,
            0, new Intent(ElapsedRealtimeAlarm.this, ElapsedRealtimeAlarm.class), 0);
```

Replace `PendingIntent.getService` with the `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` and pass the reference of your BroadcastReceiver class you made in step 1

**NOTE** :Do not forget to write the receiver and service in your manifest otherwise it won't work

**Update**:
Inside your `BroadcastReceiver's onReceive()` call the service like this

```
Intent service=new Intent(context,BackgroundService.class);
    startWakefulService(context, service);
```

this will call the onHandleIntent().

**Update 2**:
**Replace `getBaseContext()` with `this`** and change the PendingIntent.getService  as

```
Intent i=new Intent(this, BroadCastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: first: Thank you so much for your answer!

I tried this, but nothing happened. Shall I post the code?

Comment: I have also written the code in the manifest file. Also the permissions for turning wifi on/off

Comment: I updated my code based on your steps. Pls check it. And thanks

Comment: he stopped the app and gave me a `NullPointerException`on this line: `startActivity(new Intent(SpinnerTimeOnItemSelectedListener.this, ElapsedRealtimeAlarm.class));` Is this line wrong? Shall I call `ElapsedRealTimeAlarm`only with `new ElapsedRealTimeAlarm()`?

Comment: can u share the `ElapsedRealTimeAlarm's onCreate()` and the method where you are executing `startActivity(new Intent(SpinnerTimeOnItemSelectedListener.this, ElapsedRealtimeAlarm.class));`

Comment: check my update and i had already mentioned to change the `getService()` to `getBroadcast()`

Comment: sry i forgot. I did that know. It seems like he isn't even executing `SpinnerTimeOnItemSelectedListener`, because he isn't showing me the toaster

Comment: If you know how to debug please debug and inside your `onItemSelected()` put a breakpoint and check the values you are getting there.That should help.

Comment: thank you so much for your help! I didn't write the code of the `BroadCastReceiver` in the `AndroidManifest` and removed `extends Activity` from the `SpinnerTimeOnItemSelectedListener`

Answer (score 0):

Do the following it will usefull to you

Create a service that turn wifi & other operations

Create a broadcast receiver inside that onReceive method call the service

Create a pending intent and alarm for a time which you want ,when alarm time period eleapses then trigger the broadcast receiver.

Comment: ok. just to make sure:
I write the method for turning off the wifi. Than I will write a BroadCast Receiver in which I call the method for turning off wifi. And then I call in my ElapsedRealTimeAlarm class the broadcast receiver after the time elapses? Is this what you have mentioned? And is my created PendingIntent okay?
But this still doesn't answer my question. How do I know, that the time of the elapse real time alarm is over?

Comment: I tried this, but this isn't working. He stops the app